# Return the Greater of The Fields Last Column in SQL

Tags: sql

I am faced with the problem of returning the greater of the two values in the "entryId" field, that precedes the "|" mark. Each entryId field will have different numbers depending on the day, and I need to select the values that are the same, and have a higher number that precedes the "|" mark.

For example, I will need to select entryId =
'800181373149|3',
'800181373112|3',
**'800181373186|3'**

and **not** '800181373186|1'

Here is what my code is:

```
    SELECT 
     [entryId]
    ,[startDate]
    ,[endDate]
    FROM [data]
    WHERE entryId LIKE '8001813731%';
```

Here is the output:

| entryId | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 800181373149|3 | 2021-09-28T07:21:00-05:00 | 2021-09-28T16:03:00-05:00 |
| 800181373112|3 | 2021-09-28T05:21:00-07:00 | 2021-09-28T12:00:00-07:00 |
| 800181373186|3 | 2021-09-28T07:21:00-05:00 | 2021-09-28T14:00:00-05:00 |
| 800181373186|1 | 2021-09-28T07:21:00-05:00 | NULL |

Comment: Something like `with data as (select *, rownumber() over (partition by left(entryId, 12) order by entryId) as rn) select * from data where rn = 1` Not sure the proper way to parse your id value.

Answer (score 0):

Using a row_number partitioned by the part before the pipe.

```
SELECT 
  [entryId]
, [startDate]
, [endDate]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      entryId
    , startDate
    , endDate
    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(entryId, PATINDEX('%_|%', entryId)) ORDER BY entryId)
    FROM [data]
    WHERE entryId LIKE '8001813731%'
) q
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you want a single outcome with the highest value or all the vallues with the highest startdate number. Anyway in eighter case you could use the AND operator to make a second argument to add the startdate value.

```
SELECT 
 [entryId]
,[startDate]
,[endDate]
FROM [data]
WHERE entryId LIKE '8001813731%' AND startDate > 1;
```

Comment: Hardcoded values (like 8001813731) will not work with general table data, just with this specific sample table data...